# Cart items missing after login, drupal6 with ubercart

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

I using drupal 6 and ubercart latest version for my shopping site.

Unfortunately the selected items missing from the cart after login. Message showing "There are no products in your shopping cart".

Homepage : our products -> Buy now -> checkout -> login -> result in cart page = 'There are no products in your shopping cart.'

I have tried out some more fixes, But its not working for me.

For ref : http://www.ayurvedaonlineshopping.com

Thanks in advance for spent your precious time.

Comment: I got fix for this, It was a action be there for redirect the page after normal login, its afected the cart. So I remove the action.